# Expected ';' exception in I.E (JavaScript, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I'm testing my website for I.E compatibility and right away I run into plethora of problems:

```
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
webshop.html
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
webshop.html
SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'
main.js (16,18)
```

At this point I'm mostly concerned with the ; not being expected because every time i check my code it's THERE.

[image]

Comment: IE doesn't support `for...of`, that's just it.

Comment: What's the alternative then lol?

Comment: I'll add an answer for that, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE [doesn't support `for..of`](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-for..of_loops), so you can either transpile your code (e.g. [with Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-for-of/)) or use a good old [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
this.cartShop.forEach(function(item) {
    if (...) { ... }
}, this);
```

**Update**: I'm seeing now that inside the `if` block there's a `return` statement to break out of the function early, and that is why the code I suggested behaves differently. I don't recommend this kind of approach, as it leads to unexpected behaviors and code duplication. As a norm, get out of a loop using `break`.

I see you first are checking if the item is in the cart: you can do it using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
var item = this.cartShop.find(function(item) {
    return item.name === name && ...
});

if (item) {
    item.quantity += quantity;
} else {
    item = new this.Item(...);
    this.cartShop.push(item);
}

this.saveLocalCart();
```

Unfortunately, `find` is again *not* available in IE, but contrary to `for..of` you can simply provide a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill). Alternatively, you can always use your old code with a classic `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.cartShop.length; i++) {
    var item = this.cartShop[i];
    if (...) { ... }
}
```

More verbose, less readable, but still effective.

Comment: Alright, maybe an off-topic question: why does everybody use this type of way of looping over arrays then? Not a single mention about this not working on I.E.

Comment: @Vocaloidas Because new articles rightfully rely on the new ES6 syntax, and tend to discard abandoned (because that is) browsers like IE. The current usual approach is: use the new syntax, then either transpile it or use a modern enough environment.

Comment: Damn it, this function breaks my addItem function. Somehow it not only increments quantity of the item if the name, color and material match, it also adds new one in the cart. Can you help me determine the culprit? I checked to see if the variables (name, color, material) passed in the function parameters are the same to the .item variables.